# Find range of $f(\sqrt 2)$ for $f(x)=e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}+\int_0^x tf(t)dt$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function satisfying

$$f(x)=e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}+\int_0^x tf(t)\mathrm{d}t$$

Then which of the following is correct:

(A) $5<f(\sqrt 2)<6$

(B) $2<f(\sqrt 2)<3$

(C) $3<f(\sqrt 2)<4$

(D) $4<f(\sqrt 2)<5$

**My attempts so far:**

Taking derivative of $f(x)$ we get
$$f'(x)=x.e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}+x.f(x)$$
$$\frac{f'(x)}{x}-e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}=f(x)$$

On solving the differential equation we get $$f(x)=\left(C+\frac{x^2}{2}\right)e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}$$

And putting $x=\sqrt 2$ we get $f(\sqrt 2)=(C+1)e$ but I can't figure out the value of $C$.

Other attempts include writing $f(x)$ in terms of its derivative like above and putting it inside the integral, but upon solving it simply yields $f(x)$.

I also tried finding $f(2)$ and $f(1)$ as $\sqrt 2$ lies between 1 and 2 and tried finding their difference to see if it yields any insight.

$$f(1)= \sqrt e + \int_0^1tf(t)dt $$
$$f(2)= e^2 + \int_0^2tf(t)dt $$
$$ e^2 +\int_0^1tf(t)dt+ \int_1^2tf(t)dt= e^2 +\int_0^1tf(t)dt+ \int_0^1(t-1)f(t-1)dt$$

Subtracting both these equations yields:

$$f(2)-f(1)=e^2- \sqrt e + \int_0^1 (t-1)f(t-1)$$

I am at a loss on how to proceed further with this problem, any hints/ insights would be really appreciated.

**Edit:**
From comment of @Annebauval $f(0)=C=1$ and putting it in solution of differential equation we get $f(\sqrt 2)=2e \approx 5.43\,$ hence the correct answer is (A) option.

Comment: $C=f(0)=1.$____

Comment: Thanks a lot @AnneBauval

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been answered in the comments.

Comment: @AnneBauval, if you remove your close vote, I will write an answer with a different solution.

Comment: I won't but as long as the post is not closed, anybody can write another answer. @Angelo And the OP can even change their choice of which answer they accept.

Comment: @AnneBauval, please remove your close vote.

Comment: Why would someone want to close a question if it's not even a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pluggign $x=0$ in the first equation:
$$f(x)=e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}+\int_0^x tf(t)dt\ \implies\ f(0)=e^{\frac{0^2}{2}}+\int_0^0 tf(t)dt=e^0=1$$
Now plugging $x=0$ in the second equation you found for $f(x)$ we get:
$$f(x)=(C+\frac{x^2}{2})e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}\ \implies\ \ f(0)=(C+\frac{0^2}{2})e^{\frac{0^2}{2}} =Ce^0=C $$
Therefore, combining the results we get:
$$f(0)=1,\ f(0)=C\ \implies \ C=1$$
Therefore your function is
$$f(x)=(1+\frac{x^2}{2})e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}$$
and you can easily plug $\sqrt{2}$ in.

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle f(x)=e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}+\int_0^x tf(t)\,\mathrm dt\quad$ for any $\,x\in\Bbb R\,.\quad\color{blue}{(*)}$

From $(*)\,,\,$ for $\,x=\sqrt2\,,\,$ we get that

$f\left(\sqrt2\right)=e+\displaystyle\int_0^{\sqrt2}tf(t)\,\mathrm dt\,.\quad\color{blue}{(**)}$

Moreover, it results that

$\begin{align}\displaystyle D\left(e^{-\frac{x^2}2}\int_0^xtf(t)\,\mathrm dt\right)&=e^{-\frac{x^2}2}xf(x)-xe^{-\frac{x^2}2} \int_0^xtf(t)\,\mathrm dt=\\[2pt]
&=xe^{-\frac{x^2}2}\left(f(x)-\int_0^xtf(t)\,\mathrm dt\right)=\\[2pt]
&\underset{\overbrace{\text{ by using }(*)}}{=}xe^{-\frac{x^2}2}e^{\frac{x^2}2}=x=D\left(\dfrac{x^2}2\right).\end{align}$

Consequently ,

$\displaystyle e^{-\frac{x^2}2}\int_0^xtf(t)\,\mathrm dt=\dfrac{x^2}2+c\quad$ for any $\,x\in\Bbb R\,.$

It is obvious that $\,c=0\,,\,$ so we get that

$\displaystyle\int_0^xtf(t)\,\mathrm dt=\dfrac{x^2}2e^{\frac{x^2}2}\quad$ for any $\,x\in\Bbb R\,.$

In particular, for $\,x=\sqrt2\,,\,$ it results that

$\displaystyle\int_0^{\sqrt2}tf(t)\,\mathrm dt=e\,.\qquad\color{blue}{(*\!*\!*)}$

From $\,(**)\,$ and $\,(*\!*\!*)\,,\,$ it follows that

$f\left(\sqrt2\right)=2e\in\big]5,6\big[\,.$